# Bigquery: BAD_QUERY (The query requires too many resources to parse)

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a programmatically generated query for BigQuery.
It has part like

```
select *,
       IF(cond1, val1, IF(cond2, val2, IF (cond3, val3, ...))) as x
```

But when the number of IFs grows, I start getting
    Fatal error:
    Reason: invalidQuery, message: BAD_QUERY (The query requires too many     resources to parse)

I would like to know how many resources are available to parse the query and where those limits are documented. The query size itself is well under 256KB.

I didn't try yet, but wondering if rewriting query with

```
CASE WHEN THEN
```

might help here to stay under the limit.

Thank you.

Comment: FWIW, rewriting query with CASE/WHEN/THEN helped in my particular case, but I didn't check whether it can be as long as 256KB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limitation in this case is not static, and not on the length of the query, but rather on number of function nesting levels. BigQuery checks stack depth during parsing, and if it goes too deep - the error is raised.
Every function that could go deep, has variadic version, i.e. CONCAT with multiple arguments, CASE instead of IF - and this is a preferred solution for cases like that.